# Angular2, doe's EventEmitter require zone.run?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I'm using ionic2, I implemented a class:

```
import {EventEmitter, Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
@Injectable()
export class LocalPushClear extends EventEmitter<number> {
    constructor() {
      super();
    }
}
```

The class is used by on of my components to connect [cordova plugin event](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/wiki/09.-Events) to another component which subscribe to `LocalPushClear`, I listen to `clear` events, ones it fires, I emit using `LocalPushClear` and some other component subscribes:

```
this._LocalPushClear.subscribe(data => {
    // Some action is taken here
});
```

The thing is that, I was expecting automatic `change detection` to be executed  upon subscription callback execution(when its done), but it seems like there is no change detection execution at all, I have to do something like `click` a button or wrap my ***Some action*** with `zone.run`, I'm not sure if its a valid behavior or maybe I'm doing something wrong.

**Edit:**
I traces the code and it leads to [Subject](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Subject.ts), so its basically custom event emitter that angular NgZone don't know about(at least I think), but I'm sure, if anyone could confirm, maybe future explain I will be very thankful.

Comment: Seems to me that your **Some Action** manipulates some properties within the same component that has subscribed to `LocalPushClear`, at least that's what i understood from mentioning the change detection issue. If this is the case, then yes it's required to wrap the **Some Action** with `zone.run` as the change request comes from outside of component domain.

Comment: @Hani first, thanks for the comment, the thing that bugs me is that its `EventEmitter` that I'm using, exported from 'angular/core', I think when I subscribe there should already be a change detection activation within the code that implement it, I'm looking for direct answer, something like "EventEmitter that you export from angular/core won't automatically run change detection" or maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely should **not** extend `EventEmitter`. `EventEmitter` is only supposed to be used for `@Output()`s. Just use a `Subject` instead.

Angular doesn't get notified about values emitted by `EventEmitter` (when used this way) or `Subject`. Normally the code that causes the `Observable` (`Subject`) to emit new values is executed by code that causes change detection when completed for example when called from an event handler or `setTimeout`.

In your case the cause seems to be that the code that emits new values using `LocalPushClear` runs outside Angulars zone.

You can use one of the methods explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/34829089/217408 to trigger change detection after the `Observable` emits an event.

Comment: Thank you, I will use `Subject`.